# How to GroupBy a specific column for a KeyValuePair<string, DataRow>

Tags: c#

Given a `KeyValuePair<string, DataRow>`, I'd like to iterate through each entry grouping them by a specific column.

So if we had `KeyValuePair<StudentID, Student>`.

Where Student was a dataRow containing several columned student information, and I wanted to sort my foreach loop by `studentName`

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, DataRow> entry in Students.GroupBy(x => x.value["StudentName"].toString()))
```

Comment: Without backticks, `KeyValuePair<string, DataRow>` appears in a browser as "KeyValuePair". The text between the angle brackets is swallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.GroupBy()` LINQ method returns a grouping that contains the list of all the items that fit in that group.

```
foreach(IGrouping<string, DataRow> entry in Students.GroupBy(x => x.value["StudentName"].toString())) {

    var studentName = entry.Key;
    var studentsWithStudentName = entry.Select(x => x);
}
```

If your `Students` collection has a type of `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, DataRow>>`, then the `studentsWithStudentName` field here will have the type:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DataRow>>
```

Of course you could group by any field you like (say student gender) and the grouping will contain a collection of students that match that group. You can even group by generated values, say:

```
Students.GroupBy(x => x.value["StudentHeight"] > 5)
```

This would give 2 groups, one where the `Key` was true where all the students in it have a height greater than 5.